# Checking what storyboard (or view) the user is currently in

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I am building an app with multiple table views inside it that acess PDF's which share filenames. For example I have a Storyboard A with "PDF1" and storyboard B with "PDF1" also. Changing the names of the PDF's dosent really make sense based on what I have done and the way the app works. Basically i am looking for a way to check what view the user is in? (or maybe it is called a view im not sure). What I am looking for is something like this.

```
if (storyboardid == "StoryBoardA")
{
//load PDF from folderA
}

if (storyboardid == "StoryBaordB")
{
//load PDF from folderB
}
```

I couldnt find any attributes that do something like this so any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The `xcode` tag should only be used for IDE-related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I don't see any obvious way to identify the storyboard, so until you find something better, here's a round about way of doing it. First drag out a new View Controller onto each storyboard. Under the identity inspector set the "Storyboard ID" to "OrphanVC".  Under the attributes inspector set the "Title" to "StoryboardA" or "StoryboardB". Once you have an orphaned view controller set up in each storyboard, you can check which storyboard you are in with code like this

```
UIViewController *orphan = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OrphanVC"];

if ( [orphan.title isEqualToString:@"StoryboardA"] )
    NSLog( @"This is storyboard A" );
else
    NSLog( @"Must be storyboard B" );
```

Note that `self.storyboard` is a property in UIViewController, so this only works from within one of your view controller source files.